# (G)LM prediction interval with heteroscedasticity

Tags: data-transformation, heteroscedasticity, prediction-interval, generalized-least-squares

I am trying to get prediction intervals from some non-linear data which also exhibits heteroscedasticity.

```
data=structure(list(Price = c(1.03389830508475, 2.47111111111111, 
1.1976, 1.3973063973064, 1.48538011695906, 1.71847507331378, 
1.109375, 2.06751054852321, 1.65230769230769, 1.78666666666667, 
1.28307692307692, 1.01129943502825, 1.1544, 1.188, 1.13333333333333, 
1.20138888888889, 1.24302134646962, 1.220703125, 1.2962962962963, 
1.10714285714286, 1.95445920303605, 1.51724137931034, 1.03125, 
2.15384615384615, 1.66666666666667, 1.89819376026273, 2.16142557651992, 
2.27272727272727, 1.66666666666667, 3.45925925925926, 1.38709677419355, 
1.41843971631206, 1.048828125, 1.23318385650224, 1.22787193973635, 
2.49707602339181, 1.08156028368794, 1.08977556109726, 1.69023569023569, 
1.1503416856492, 1.27041742286751, 1.28609625668449, 1.3542600896861, 
1.07052186177715, 1.92307692307692, 1.11637931034483, 3.44444444444444, 
1.22222222222222, 1.32682926829268, 1.95622895622896, 1.14519056261343, 
1.30902777777778, 1.53230769230769, 2.33333333333333, 1.56296296296296, 
2.06432748538012, 1.49579831932773, 1.1625, 1.35606060606061, 
1.26913580246914, 2.13636363636364, 2.44888888888889, 1.25806451612903, 
1.08203125, 1.11864406779661, 1.02277039848197, 1.53107344632768, 
2.20754716981132, 1.11320754716981, 1.02346041055718, 2.17159763313609, 
4.52941176470588, 1.60818713450292, 1.246875, 1.32075471698113, 
1.12820512820513, 1.9958071278826, 1.81528662420382, 1.1464, 
2.09615384615385, 1.08717948717949, 1.27407407407407, 1.003125, 
1.25436408977556, 1.12444444444444, 1.06289308176101, 1.4, 1.43076923076923, 
1.17424242424242, 1.35555555555556, 1.28223844282238, 1.94339622641509, 
1.83847549909256, 1.08189655172414, 1.52631578947368, 1.11555555555556, 
1.28205128205128, 1.290625, 1.42577030812325, 1.04273504273504, 
3.64864864864865, 1.1952861952862, 1.4390243902439, 1.52188552188552, 
1.51851851851852, 2.44230769230769, 1.30496453900709, 1.03530751708428, 
1.04627249357326, 2.11111111111111, 1.84870848708487, 1.33687943262411, 
1.51231527093596, 1.78345498783455, 2.33962264150943, 2.46666666666667, 
2.13216957605985, 3.5982905982906, 1.36694677871148, 1.14655172413793, 
1.92948717948718, 3.00854700854701, 1.00332225913621, 1.52045133991537, 
1.42036124794745, 1.0125284738041, 1.020964360587, 1.06329113924051, 
1.01129943502825, 1.73706896551724, 1.27170868347339, 1.72820512820513, 
1.07758620689655, 2.09227871939736, 1.24858757062147, 1.27005347593583, 
1.1384, 1.77805486284289, 1.25387870239774, 1.171875, 1.94827586206897, 
1.66379310344828, 1.30493273542601, 1.05923836389281, 1.16949152542373, 
2.76, 1.74358974358974, 2.27118644067797, 1.08029197080292, 4.5, 
1.33125, 1.33575317604356, 1.13965087281796, 1.0733137829912, 
1.47953216374269, 1.23719165085389, 2.31964809384164, 1.56756756756757, 
1.05082592121982, 1.8828125, 1.19868637110016, 1.64224137931034, 
2.28301886792453, 3.47317073170732, 1.73706896551724, 1.24678663239075, 
1.11458333333333, 1.24137931034483, 2.53488372093023, 1.32, 1.13461538461538, 
1.08210180623974, 1.96059113300493, 1.25365853658537, 1.27586206896552, 
2.46198830409357, 1.43076923076923, 1.27734375, 1.66666666666667, 
2.01496259351621, 1.11181702668361, 2.68148148148148, 1.06726457399103, 
1.13965087281796, 6, 1.48076923076923, 1.22222222222222, 1.23692307692308, 
1.63157894736842, 1.21254355400697, 1.02547770700637, 1.06737588652482, 
2.27777777777778, 1.1171875, 1.73542600896861, 1.07344632768362, 
1.0427807486631, 1.1864406779661, 2.00975609756098, 1.35828877005348
), Quantity = c(0.8975, 0.1225, 0.335555555555556, 0.4125, 0.51, 
0.3075, 0.6825, 0.07, 0.195, 0.3575, 0.55, 0.9675, 0.524444444444444, 
0.402222222222222, 0.8125, 0.7575, 0.557777777777778, 0.546666666666667, 
0.833333333333333, 0.65, 0.0075, 0.4825, 0.9425, 0.2375, 0.153333333333333, 
0.0666666666666667, 0.0125, 0.075, 0.483333333333333, 0.04, 0.783333333333333, 
0.4675, 0.84, 0.78, 0.345, 0.12, 0.915, 0.875555555555556, 0.1625, 
0.373333333333333, 0.375555555555556, 0.465, 0.63, 0.853333333333333, 
0.395, 0.845, 0.194805194805195, 0.95, 0.61, 0.09, 0.7, 0.6125, 
0.29, 0.292207792207792, 0.4075, 0.195, 0.52, 0.4325, 0.54, 0.51, 
0.15, 0.1525, 0.866666666666667, 0.885, 0.8375, 0.975, 0.325, 
0.276666666666667, 0.906666666666667, 0.96, 0.0234113712374582, 
0.100671140939597, 0.4775, 0.315, 0.415, 0.78, 0.055, 0.0222222222222222, 
0.597777777777778, 0.345, 0.956521739130435, 0.635, 0.89, 0.706666666666667, 
0.905, 0.875, 0.42, 0.74247491638796, 0.725, 0.6075, 0.573333333333333, 
0.316666666666667, 0.0644444444444444, 0.9, 0.5075, 0.905, 0.7125, 
0.1775, 0.56, 0.98, 0.1, 0.65, 0.2475, 0.32, 0.633333333333333, 
0.295, 0.535, 0.876666666666667, 0.936666666666667, 0.17, 0.00334448160535117, 
0.5225, 0.291111111111111, 0.17, 0.183333333333333, 0.135, 0.0333333333333333, 
0.045, 0.61, 0.716666666666667, 0.38, 0.07, 0.994987468671679, 
0.117777777777778, 0.315555555555556, 1, 0.94, 0.9175, 0.945, 
0.163333333333333, 0.6875, 0.464882943143813, 0.916666666666667, 
0.01, 0.5525, 0.515, 0.651111111111111, 0.18, 0.44, 0.623333333333333, 
0.0833333333333333, 0.4525, 0.69, 0.908888888888889, 0.6925, 
0.06, 0.3825, 0.0175, 0.86, 0.116666666666667, 0.1575, 0.255555555555556, 
0.826666666666667, 0.815, 0.56, 0.6225, 0.05, 0.466666666666667, 
0.751111111111111, 0.17, 0.611111111111111, 0.283333333333333, 
0.256666666666667, 0.01, 0.196666666666667, 0.656666666666667, 
0.8475, 0.683333333333333, 0.137844611528822, 0.475, 0.87, 0.853333333333333, 
0.0555555555555556, 0.6525, 0.551111111111111, 0.1575, 0.759197324414716, 
0.5475, 0.566666666666667, 0.102222222222222, 0.562222222222222, 
0.13, 0.9775, 0.804444444444444, 0.0671140939597315, 0.5425, 
0.957792207792208, 0.61, 0.4525, 0.58, 0.897777777777778, 0.94, 
0.416666666666667, 0.8225, 0.175, 0.86, 0.9275, 0.6525, 0.1725, 
0.415)), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = "data.frame")
```

which looks like this

[image]

My first approach was to use a gls model to include the variance structure, but then I learned that there is no option to get prediction intervals from a gls model (that I could find).

My second approach was to use a Box Cox transformation, get rid of the heteroscedasticity, get the prediction intervals and then untransform the data to the original scale. But I am stuck on the last step of untransforming the data. How can I achieve this?

```
library(MASS)
bc=boxcox(Price~Quantity,data=data,lambda=seq(-3,3,0.1),plotit=F)
lambda=bc$x[which.max(bc$y)]
data$PriceBC=((data$Price^lambda-1)/lambda)
mod=lm(PriceBC~Quantity,data=data)
plot(mod)
pred=predict(mod,data,interval="prediction")
```

If not, is there a better / simpler way of achieving this?